# C++. Vector of pointers and using the vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

For part of my assignment I need to create a vector of pointers that point to shape objects. I have a few different classes, the base class Shape, and a few derived classes such as Circle and Rectangle. In the main I need to construct the vector and then pass the vector to a function that will expand the dimensions of the shape. So the function will multiply the radius, the length and the width by a certain number. This is my code so far:

```
vector<Shape*> shapes;
shapes.push_back(circ1);
shapes.push_back(rect1);
```

with circ1 and rect 1 being objects from the class Circle and Rectangle. I also defined circ1 and rect1 but didnt include the code here.

my function is called expandAll(), this is what i tried to do:

```
void expandAll(vector<Shape*> shapes, int factor)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++)
   {
      shapes[i] = shapes[i] * factor;
   }
}
```

This is wrong due to the error that popped up. To sum up, I need help creating a vector of pointers and using that vector in a function. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "due to the error that popped up." Which one?

Comment: Is vector of pointers mandated by your teacher? I ask so because I recommend against it in general.

Comment: If you really need a vector of pointers you want to use smart pointers instead of row pointers.

Answer (score 1):

`shapes[i]` is a pointer. Which you can't multiply by `factor`. You need to dereference the pointer, `*shapes[i]`. This assumes that your `Shape` class (and the derived classes) override the `*` (multiply, not dereference) operator.

And when you fix that, assigning it back to `shapes[i]` is also going to fail. Likely you'll need to dereference that, too.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with the incomplete code you've shown in your question.

`shapes` is a

```
vector<Shape*>
```

Therefore, `shapes[i]` gives you a `Shape *`. The shown code is equivalent to:

```
Shape *p = shapes[i];

shapes[i] = p * factor;
```

This alternative makes it clear what the problem is. Multiplication of a pointer to some object is completely undefined in C++. There's no such thing.

In C++, you can't multiply a pointer. That's an undefined operation. It makes no sense to multiply a pointer by anything.

What you are most likely trying to do is overload the multiplication operator in your base `Shapes` class.

However, assuming that your `Shapes` class has a virtual `operator*` overload, this still will not work. This is because, as you've described, `Shapes` is a possibly abstract base class, and, as you know, an abstract class is not assignable/copyable (without an overloaded operator for that, which I think is unlikely here), and if your base class is not abstract, the assignment operator will slice it away. (Not to mention the likely memory leakage).

So, even if `Shapes` has an overloaded multiplication operator, `(*shapes[i]) = (*shapes[i]) * factor;` will still fail.

The only way for this approach to work would be if you virtually overload the `*=` operator, in your abstract base class, and invoke it as

```
(*shapes[i]) *= factor;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you probably tried multiplying **the object itself**:

```
shapes[i] = shapes[i] * factor;
```

In spite of that `shapes[i]` is the **pointer** to an object, it is a bad idea.

You have to change (multiply) the **properties** of the object, so use something as

```
shapes[i] -> radius = (shapes[i] -> radius) * factor;
```

or - more compact -

```
shapes[i] -> radius *= factor;
```

I don't know the names of the properties of your shapes, so instead or `radius` use appropriate name or *names* (as rectangles have both **width** and **hight**) and you have decide, too, if the object is of a class `Circle` or `Rectangle`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't give the code, but I assume this is the classical exercice about  polymorphism.
So first, assuming you create the circles with `Circle circ1, circ2;` then you *must* store their adress in the vector, thus:

```
vector<Shape*> shapes;
shapes.push_back( &circ1 );
shapes.push_back( &circ2 );
```

Then, your function should be:

```
void expandAll( vector<Shape*>& shapes, int factor)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++)
      *shapes[i] = *shapes[i] * factor;
}
```

But this assumes that your classes all define the `*` operator, which may not be trivial, if you are a beginner.
And its better to pass it as a reference, so the whole vector doesn't get copied.

Answer (score 0):

```
void expandAll(vector<Shape*>& shapes, int factor)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++)
   {
      *shapes[i] = *shapes[i] * factor;
   }
}
```

You should try this thing above.

```
shapes[i] = shapes[i] * factor; // Here you're multypling pointers, instead of objects you want
```

Anyway, I think that still wouldn't work if the operator*() on Shape isn't defined.